# Insert in the collection present into another server using angular.js and node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, body-parser

This is my controller code from which I want to send he request to the server where the server will store the data in the collection.

```
$scope.addIdeas = function(){
console.log($scope.idea);
var post_data = null;
post_data = $scope.idea;
console.log(post_data);
$http({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3300/myroute/',
            method: 'post',

        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(res);
               post_data = $scope.idea;
               console.log('from the function add' + post_data);


        });

};
```

Then this is my server code where I am getting the request to put it in the collection.

```
//Adding the ideas to database
app.post('/addIdeas', function(req, res){
console.log('i get req from idea controller');
console.log(req.body);

db.ideas.insert(req.body, function (err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
});

});
```

It's value is `null` when I request `req.body`.

Comment: you are not sending the data along with the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add post data in request:

```
$http({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3300/myroute/',
        method: 'post',
        data:{test:'test'}//Your data object
    })
```

Comment: Thnaks you ... its working now we have to add param to it data: $.param({test: test})